# Is it possible to programmatically get the client-side bundle size a user sees in production?

Tags: javascript, browser

We'd like to track the bundle size our customers have to download for real in production, so I'm wondering if there exists a browser API that can tell you what the client side bundle size is/was for the current session?

This would allow us to report it and keep track of its change over time! Even if it only works in one or two browsers, it would already be a good start.

Comment: Don't you control the server that actually delivers the client code?

Comment: We do, but what gets sent to the client is complex and depends on where you land at first. It'd be great if we could have the exact answer from each client, reliably.